# RailsTutorial rspec test is failling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm ashamed to make this question but I can't find my error, I am once again doing the rails tutorial from Michael Hartl, since the first time I wasn't able to do the proper TDD, anyways I have managed to have working every single test but one! the thing is that I test it manually on rails' console and it worked, I tried to reset the db with `rake db:reset` and `rake test:prepare` and obviously re-populating the db `rake db:populate` ok, straight to the point... I have the following test

```
describe "status" do
      let(:unfollowed_posts) do
        FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: FactoryGirl.create(:user))
      end
      let(:followed_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before do
        @user.follow!(followed_user)
        3.times { followed_user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem Ipsum") }
      end

      its (:feed) { should include(newer_micropost) }
      its (:feed) { should include(older_micropost) }
      its (:feed) { should_not include(unfollowed_posts) }
      its (:feed) do
        followed_user.microposts.each do |micropost|
          should include(micropost)
        end
      end
    end
```

according to me, everything is ok, I test it manually on `rails console`, however when runing the spec with `rpsec spec/models/user_spec.rb` it comes up with the following error

`Failures:`

**1) User micropost associations status feed**

```
     Failure/Error: should include(micropost)
       expected #&lt;ActiveRecord::Relation [#&lt;Micropost id: 355, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: 702, created_at: "2014-05-10 03:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47"&gt;, #&lt;Micropost id: 354, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: 702, created_at: "2014-05-09 04:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47"&gt;]&gt; to include #&lt;Micropost id: 358, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: *703*, created_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47"&gt;
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
       -[#&lt;Micropost id: 358, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: *703*, created_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47"&gt;]
       +[#&lt;Micropost id: 355, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: 702, created_at: "2014-05-10 03:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47"&gt;,
       + #&lt;Micropost id: 354, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: 702, created_at: "2014-05-09 04:34:47", updated_at: "2014-05-10 04:34:47"&gt;]
</code>
```

I don't understand why the user_id is changed if the code 3.times { followed_user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem Ipsum") } doesn't touch followed_user at all, so... that's my headache now, why is this happening? is it a bogus behavior on rspec, thanks in advance, and sry for this dull question.

Comment: Which version of Rails you're using and what's the place you are on the tutorial ?

Comment: I am currently using rails 4.0.4 and ruby 2.0.0, using postgresql for the database, that's the last [chapter here](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-motivation_and_strategy) the code sample is the one listed on 11.41

Answer (score 0):

you need to change you `feed` method in `user.rb` file

from

```
def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", user)
end
```

to

```
def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

as well as add method `self.from_users_followed_by` to your `micropost.rb` file

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) or user_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id)
end
```